# Populate manually a HasMap just like a dictionary in pyhton

Tags: java, arrays

In python I have such a dictionary and I would like to achieve something very similar with java.

```
eva_mp = {"M": "11-14:30", "G": "11-14:30", "E": "11-14:30", "A": "11-14:30", "Z": "11-14:30"}
```

I tried with:

```
public static Hashtable<String,String> convertMonth=new Hashtable<String,String>();
```

and/or

```
public static  String pippo = ["MONDAY":"Lunedi",];
```

In the first example, googling, I only found how to populate it via `put` and that's not what I want.

In the second example I just get `syntax errors` whatever I do.
Since I will need several "`dictionaries`" I would need to know how to do it